# Handling database open and close in subroutines

Tags: mysql, go, goroutine

I'm implementing a code where I need to perform few actions at fixed intervals.

Few of them are related to fetching data from mysql database.

To schedule these actions at fixed interval I'm using gocron. It is working quite well.

For the database, as of now, I'm creating an instance at the start of main program and passing it to subroutines. I'm using https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx to work with DB.

The flow of code is:

i- initialise resources. For eg db = sql.Open;put the DB in common struct to pass to all subroutine

ii- scheduleActions using gocron (pass resources as needed)

iii- actions are specific subroutine that perform task as needed using given resource (for eg DB)

I got few cases where the mysql service needs to be restarted.

Then as expected I get error stating invalid connection. some thing like

```
[mysql] packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
[mysql] packets.go:130: write tcp 127.0.0.1:36191->127.0.0.1:3306: write: broken pipe
[mysql] connection.go:312: invalid connection
```

To get around this, I did an implementation to acquire the DB connection with in the subroutine and close with defer db.close(). With this I'm getting error related to too many open connections. I have checked for proper close of rows, as well usage of scan. And see the recommendations are being followed.

I would like to understand how to go about DB open and close handling in my case.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sync.Once` to prevent this:

```
var conn *sql.DB // Set package-wide, but not exported
var once sync.Once

func GetConnection() *sql.DB {
    once.Do(func() {
        var err error
        if conn, err = sql.Open("postgres", "<credentials>"); err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
        conn.SetMaxOpenConns(20) // Sane default
        conn.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
        conn.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Nanosecond)
    })
    return conn
}
```

Read this: https://aaronoellis.com/articles/preventing-max-connection-errors-in-go

Comment: Thanks Alireza. I'll give this a try and let know if it works.